# jQuery-like library with vanillaJS

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm building a jQuery-like library, but there's a bug in here somewhere where the line `$('#hello').addClass('blue');` didn't work as intended.

```js
class DOM {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = document.querySelectorAll(element);
        Object.assign(this, this.element);
    }

    addClass(className) {
        return this.each(function(el){
            console.log(el);
            this.classList.add(className);
        });
    }

    removeClass(className){
        return this.each(function(el) {
            this.classList.remove(className);
        });
    }

    each(callback) {
        // convert this to Array to use for...of
        for ( let el of Array.from(this) ) {
            console.log(el);
            callback.call( el );
        }

    // return this for chaining
    return this;
    }
}

let $ = (selector) => new DOM(selector);
$('#hello').addClass('blue');
```

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.green {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">
  Hello!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the way you are assigning the element to this using assign won't work. I'm not sure if it's really desirable, just keep a reference to the element, it will be less confusing.

Aside from that, you also need to use forEach instead of each for NodeList collections, altering the addClass in your fiddle to the following allows it work:

```
  addClass(className) {
    return this.element.forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.add(className);
    });
  }
```

Edit: Closer inspection I can you were not really using `each`, that was an internal method of your class.

A full version of your code would look like:

```
class DOM {
  constructor(element){
    this.element = document.querySelectorAll(element);
  }

  addClass(className) {
    return this.element.forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.add(className);
    });
  }

  removeClass(className){
    return this.element.forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove(className);
    });
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to keep the `each` method, something like this works too:

```
class DOM {
    constructor(element){
    this.element = document.querySelectorAll(element);
  }

  addClass(className) {
    return this.each((el) => {
        el.classList.add(className);
    });
  }

    removeClass(className){
    return this.each((el) => {
        el.classList.remove(className);
    });
  }

  each(callback){
    // convert this to Array to use for...of
    for (let el of Array.from(this.element)) {
      callback(el);
    }

    // return this for chaining
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to use the internal method `each` because I wanted to create chaining. `Object.assign(this, this.element)` should work also, as I checked in console.